# Broke my Seapora AquariumController. What are my options?

Tags: aquarium, fish, community-aquarium, equipment

[image: Broken Controller]

I'm a fool and dropped the controller. The people at the store I bought it from didn't really have a solution on how to resolve this. Does anyone know how I should go about replacing it?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, this controller is connected to some device, and buying a new controller won't work cause it should come with the device? Something like that happened to me some years ago with a machine used to take pictures in a special box.. you have to contact the manufacturer of the thing, only they can help. If it's only the screen, maybe someone skilled could repair it and order the part online if possible.

Comment: I just bought a Seapora pro 85 that has the same remote. but I am unable to do anything with it. Did you get manual with yours? Trying to locate any guide for the remote.

Answer (score 1):

How much have you googled? Can you contact the manufacturer directly? I found seaporaproducts.com which is just a warranty page (but if you know the logo, you’ll be able to tell if it’s them or not). From there, I looked at [Whois.com](https://www.whois.com/whois/seaporaproducts.com) and it’s registered to GoDaddy. I might be fishing off the wrong pier, though... FWIW, GoDaddy has a BigAlsOnline email address registering the domain name, and they do stock some seapora stuff, so it might be worth contacting Big Al's.

Alternatively, it might be worth trying your local phone-fixing shop to see if they can repair it.

Comment: I couldn't find anything really useful for seapora, easytouch or aquariumcontroller (names on the devices). I brought it to 2 pet stores and 1 cell phone repair and no luck.

Comment: My first stop was Big Al's and the manager didn't really know what to do. He said he'll look into it and get back to me.... but yeah. I'll try their home office perhaps and see if I can get a proper answer.